# Input to Output wont change words in result

Tags: javascript

I was working on something recently and I was struggling to get the result of A and place into B's box. Now I want to replace everything that says /test/ and replace it with 'banana'. But so far I haven't been able to get this to work. Can somebody explain where I am going wrong?

**Javascript**

```
<script>
function sync()
{
  var A = document.getElementById('A');
  var B = document.getElementById('B');

  A = someString.replace(/test/, 'banana');
  B.value = A.value;

}
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Initially A and B both are objects, in the third line of the function, you are actually assigning string value to A, so you will have to use A instead of A.value

```
  A = someString.replace(/test/, 'banana');
  B.value =A; // because A has string value now
```

In order to make your code work, do this

```
A.value = someString.replace(/test/, 'banana');
```

Comment: What.. so your saying to remove '.value' but in the second example you re-add it?

Comment: use A.value to make your function work as the second solution, I edited the answer

Comment: @John  The first solution is for explanation why your code didn't work and the second solution is how you code should be like to make your function work.

Comment: Ah, I see now. Haha, my mistake.

Comment: will do in a 2 minutes, I have to wait. hehe.

Comment: I have to wait, it for the answer to be able to be selected.

Answer (score -2):

i would say to try:

```
    var pattern = /test/;
    A.value = someString.replace(pattern, 'banana');
```